# How to Import data from a csv file in Flex Mobile 4.6 local database?

Tags: sqlite, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I am trying to create a mobile app using flex-mobile flash builder 4.6, which shows three ComboBoxes.
I am reading values from a local SQLite built-in database.
I want to insert bulk values in my database viz. from a csv/text file.
Any idea,how should I go about it?
Thanks in Advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Run `sqlite3.exe your_database_file.db` and execute

```
  .mode csv your_table_name
  .import your_csv_file your_table_name
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help. Although I want to import the csv file programmatically from my app because then it can be packaged along with the application.